# Convert number INT in minutes to TIME in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, converters

I need help, my problem is to convert an integer representing minutes into a TIME data type in MySQL
example:

```
 duration   -->   time
    60          01:00:00
    40          00:40:00
    30          00:30:00
   120          02:00:00
```

The duration column is my field in my database, I need to do a query that field turning into a time data type, in the command SELECT
example:

```
SELECT any_function(duration)
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This should get you what you want. Multiply your minutes by 60 to get seconds then convert to time.

`SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(duration*60)`

refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html for time related functions in MySQL.

Comment: @RodrigoAguilar No problem, glad I could help. If this answer suited you please accept it as the answer so others can easily solve this problem in the future should it arise.

Answer (score 5):

My problem was integer hours to time ie: `8.5 was 8` an a half hours

Use the same method as above but multiply again

```
SEC_TO_TIME((ScheduledTime*60)*60) give you 08:30:00
```