# SQL Query - How To Convert Second data to Hours

Tags: sql

It's my SQL query. duration's data in seconds. I want to convert like 12000
second --> 3:20:00

```sql
SELECT `user` AS vpn_user,
            `remip` AS peerip,
            `duration` AS vpn_duration,
             FROM_ITIME(`itime`-`duration`) AS start_time,
             FROM_ITIME(`itime`) AS end_time,
            `tunneltype` AS vpn_type
FROM $log
WHERE $filter
            AND `subtype`='vpn'
            AND `tunneltype` IN ('ssl-tunnel')
            AND `action` = 'tunnel-down'
            AND COALESCE(NULLIFNA(`user`), IPSTR(`remip`)) IS NOT NULL
            AND `tunnelid` IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY vpn_user,
                peerip,
                vpn_duration,
                start_time,
                end_time,
                vpn_type
```

Comment: Since you are a new player here, i would suggest you would be more specific in the tags as SQL is a broad term, and the answer could be much different according to the specific engine you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Initially I posted an answer for SQL Server but then I noticed you are probably using MySQL. So check the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20705999/convert-number-int-in-minutes-to-time-in-mysql).

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(12000)
```