# How to divide hour to minute in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `Time` with column `StartTime`:

| ID | StartTime |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 08:00:00 |

Now I want to find the time difference between `StartTime` and `09:00:00`, divide it by 3 to result in 20min. How can I do something like this?

```
SELECT ('09:00:00' - (SELECT StartTime FROM Time) / 3)
```

Output should be `'00:20:00'`

Comment: Refer to the [TIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time.html) data type, TIME [literals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html) and TIME [functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

Comment: `select (hour('09:00:00')-hour('08:00:00'))/3*60;` gives 20, and then you do [Convert number INT in minutes to TIME in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20705999/convert-number-int-in-minutes-to-time-in-mysql)   (But `TIME_TO_SEC` and `SEC_TO_TIME` might be easier, generally speaking)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A combination OF `TIMEDIFF` and `TIME_TO SEC` and `SEC_TO_TIME`

> ```
> select SEC_TO_TIME(TIME_TO_SEC(timediff('09:00:00','08:00:00')) / 3)
> ```
>
> ```
> | SEC_TO_TIME(TIME_TO_SEC(timediff('09:00:00','08:00:00')) / 3) |
> | :------------------------------------------------------------ |
> | 00:20:00.0000                                                 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ebe57d9ed79dd93c43040470353360b5)*